# Can an Arduino detect a current drop

Tags: arduino, magnetics

I have to detect a magnet with an Arduino for a personal project. I was wondering if using a magnetoresistor and detecting the current drop was possible. I understand that using a Hall effect sensor is the easiest method, but I wanted to know if it was possible. How would I integrate it in this case.

Comment: Where are you going to get a magnetoresistor from?

Comment: Unclear at present, I was just wondering if it was possible, and not considering the specifics of sourcing

Comment: Then yes, lots of things are possible. Is it possible questions tend to be bad questions to ask since they are extremely broad, close-ended questions and no one really learns anything from the answers.

Comment: How would I integrate it in that case\

Comment: Well, first you need to get a magneto resistor and I guess wrap a bunch of wire around it like an inductor to concentrate the magnetic field so the effect is increased for the same amount of current? But good look finding a magneto resistor on its own.

Comment: your smartphone probably has a magnetometer built in .... you could do some quick experiments with the magnet and your phone

Comment: @JakeArthur the answer could be really trivially adding a single passive component (assuming you know Ohm's law, but seeing the site is called "Electrical Engineering", I'm going to go ahead and assume you do), or it could be extremely complicated, involving a cryogenic transimpedance amplifier. Depends on your magnetoresistor. So, will need a few numbers before a sensibly compact answer could be given.

Comment: A Hall sensor or a GMR (giant magneto resistive effect) (vaguely close to what you want) or a MEMS magnetic field detector, or even a  mechanical deflecting sensor (compass needle like) all have the advantage of availability and or working in a known way.

Answer (score 0):

To detect a magnet it is useful to start by using a magnetic field detector. "detecting the current drop" is a step off the main path - unless you are actually trying to detect a current drop - if so, you should say so.

A **Hall sensor** does just what you want - and is available off the shelf at good

prices and with well defined characteristics -  why would you not start there?

A **GMR (giant magneto resistive** effect) sensor measures change in magnetic alignment - also off the shelf. (vaguely closer to what you want)

A MEMS gyroscope and accelerometer package often incorporates a **3 axis magnetic field detector** as a bonus, What's not to like?

A **fluxgate** sensor will probably do what you want.

Even a  mechanical deflecting sensor (**compass needle** like) can be bought or built from scratch.

All have the advantage of availability and or working in a known way.

But and :-) - **you can but magneto resistive sensors off the shelf** -  eg [here - from Arrow](https://www.arrow.com/en/categories/sensors/magnetoresistive-sensors)